# float issue on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css-float

I have an issue with this site:
http://carolinegeraghty.azurewebsites.net

I use a jQuery "bounce" effect on the text boxes.

This works fine in Firefox. But not on Chrome.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a solution. Just changed the min and max widths and heights. So you can disregard this thread